# wraps/breaks different in chrome / firefox

Tags: css, word-wrap, word-break

breaks/wraps seem to behave differently across Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

**Google Chrome:**
[image]

**Mozilla Firefox:**
[image]

Both have the exact same CSS:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-all;
display: inline-block;
```

But I can't get it consistent. I want to move long words to the next line, and if they still don't fit, then break them anywhere (like Google Chrome does in my picture).

How can I get Mozilla Firefox to do it too? What is the right way to do it and why?

Comment: Are you sure 1 of the browsers doesn't have css cached? (firefox) on my pc they both work the same: https://jsfiddle.net/vc7qumxg/ . Looks like firefox is missing the inline-block in your case.

Comment: @JoelHarkes Well, they are divs, so they wouldn't look like that without the `inline-block`. I agree with you that the OP probably just has a caching issue though. Firefox is notorious for caching old CSS.

Comment: @devman If clearing the cache doesn't help, can you post a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?